# Python/Qt Designer: Adress a QPushButton without self

Tags: python, qt

I have a QPushButton, called 'StartButton' in my MainWindow. The Button's name, position and everything else is defined in the Qt Designer, so I don't define anything in my programm.

I want to replace `self.StartButton.clicked....` with something like `QtGui.MyMainWindow.StartButton.clicked....`
Is that possible at all and what should I write instead of `self`?

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtGui.QFileDialog):

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
       uic.loadUi('MyMainWindow.ui', self)

       self.StartButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.do_something())
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Also: will not work. `self` refers to an *instance* of the `MainWindow` class. You act upon instances, not classes themselves (except for `staticmethod`s).

Comment: Working with Buttons, TextEdits etc. causes problems in other classes (maybe I have a problem with inheritance), because writing `MainWindow.StartButton....` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your line should read:

```
self.StartButton.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
```

I made two changes:

- First, I removed the parentheses. You were calling `do_something`, rather than passing it as an argument to `connect`.
- The second change is replacing `MainWindow` with `self`. I realize that you want to avoid this, but `MainWindow` is merely the class. `self` is the instance of `MainWindow` you are trying to connect to.

Note: you are also inheriting from two different widgets (`QMainWindow` and `QFileDialog`), which leads to undefined behavior in Qt. Unfortunately, you have to pick one or the other or things will break.